# Add text suffix to item quantity in WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I've found below on Stackoverflow, which adds suffix text to the Basket page, but what do I need to include so adds suffix text on Checkout page too?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_quantity_input_field', 'wtwh_echo_qty_front_add_cart' );
function wtwh_echo_qty_front_add_cart() {
   echo '<span class="qty-suff">(Tonnes)</span>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a prefix to the item quantity in checkout, use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'wtwh_echo_qty_front_add_checkout' );
function wtwh_echo_qty_front_add_checkout( $quantity_html ) {
    return $quantity_html . ' <span class="qty-suff">(Tonnes)</span>'; 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.